# set flag to remove duplicate records from a file based on some values of the record

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a file having the following records (pipe delimited):

```
SK200-10|ALBUMIN-SK|INS|SEKURE ALBUMIN 2 X 65ML|REAG-IVD|SEKI-PEI|90|14IAG|KIDNEY/LIVER|MD|NA|0|U|MFGPRO|15-May-2014|15-May-2014|MFGPRO|CAPPROD
P/G-PPR|NA-INS|INS|GEWINDEFLASCHE +DECKEL ROT|NON-REAG|ZINSSER|0|NA|NA|NA|NON-REAG|0|U|DM|3-Jun-2014|3-Jun-2014|MFGPRO|UKPROD
P/G-PPR|NA-INS|INS|GEWINDEFLASCHE +DECKEL ROT|NON-REAG|ZINSSER|0|NA|NA|NA|NON-REAG|0|U|DM|3-Jun-2014|3-Jun-2014|DM|QADDB
2898|OTHER-RT|RT|PRINTED MEMBRANE, ADENOVIRUS|NON-REAG|SEKI-SD|60|NA|NA|NA|NA|0|U|MFGPRO|24-Apr-2013|24-Apr-2013|MFGPRO|PACEPROD
```

In these pipe delimited records:
The first value is the item number.
The 13th value is the status flag.
The last value is the database name.

Check for duplicate records based on the Item number from the `UKPROD` and `QADDB` database.
If a duplicate is found: Change the value of the status flag (13th value) to 'X' from the `QADDB` database.

For example, in the above 4 records:

The item number is same for the 2nd and the 3rd record. I then check if they exist between the `UKPROD` and the `QADDB` databases. If yes, the I mark the status flag as 'X' for the record from `QADDB` database.

Comment: Does the `UKPROD` entry for a given item number always precede any possible `QADDB` entry? or is the order indeterminate?

Comment: If I am understanding your question, yes the order of the item records is indeterminate. we have nightly scripts running which consolidates these item records from 4 databases. and we have to mark status flag of the records from qaddb which matches with teh records from ukprod.

Answer (score 1):

If the order of the `UKPROD` and `QADDB` entries for each product ID is not fixed, then I think you will need to read and process the file twice - on the first pass, construct a lookup table of all the products (field #1) in the `UKPROD` database, and on the second pass check each product that's shown against `QADDB` for presence in `UKPROD`. For example, one possible solution in `awk` might be

```
awk -F\| '
BEGIN{OFS=FS}; 
NR==FNR {if ($NF=="UKPROD") ukprod[$1]++; next} 
NR!=FNR {if (ukprod[$1] && $NF=="QADDB") $13="X"} 
1' yourfile yourfile
```

but likely there are better implementations. If `UKPROD` and `QADDB` refer to actual databases, then it might be more efficient to do an actual database query instead of test-processing the flat file.

Comment: Thanks much. I will look into this and see if it works for me.Unfortunately, we cannot do an actual database query because the qaddb and ukprod are on different platforms. so the only way is scripting.